# Problems exposing a RIA services as SOAP, Json, etc

Tags: c#, wcf, json, soap, ria

I'm trying to expose an existing RIA service with SOAP and JSON.

In the web.config, serviceModel section, I've put:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<domainServices>
  <endpoints>
    <add name="OData" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ODataEndpointFactory, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="Soap" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory, Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="Json" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.JsonEndpointFactory, Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </endpoints>
</domainServices>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

In MyDomainService there is:

```
    [Query(IsDefault=true)]
    public IEnumerable<UserItem> GetUsers()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Users;
    }
```

I've tried the following URLs:

> http://10.0.0.191:27070/Manager-Web-MyDomainService.svc/GetUsers
>
> http://10.0.0.191:27070/Manager-Web-MyDomainService.svc/Soap/GetUsers
>
> http://10.0.0.191:27070/Manager-Web-MyDomainService.svc/Json/GetUsers
>
> http://10.0.0.191:27070/Manager-Web-MyDomainService.svc/OData/GetUsers

and I get just blank pages.

I've enabled tracing and in the log I see the warning "Configuration evaluation context not found".

Anybody who can help me with this?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
Gianluca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've sorted out almost everything. My configuration was correct. Problems were elsewhere. Let me share my findings:

First of all, I've found out that OData requires a '/' at the end of the URL. Also, I was wrongly thinking that it is necessary to recall the service URL with at the end the name of the method. Something like: http:///oData/. It turned out that by calling just http:///oData/ I was getting all the expected data.

At the contrary, Json does not want the trailing '/'. A correct URL is like: http:///Json/. This time it's been necessary to indicate the method. I'm also starting to understand better the meaning of the attributes Query, Invoke, etc. An INVOKE-decorated method is exposed as JSON only if it has the property HasSideEffect=false.

I am still having trouble exposing the same methods via SOAP. If someone wants to contribute and help me out, please feel free to add more info here. I'll post more information as soon as I get further results.

Cheers,
Gianluca.

Comment: Your SOAP endpoint should be http://10.0.0.192:27070/Manager-Web-MyDomainService.svc.